# Interrupting and canceling a queue of queries

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I have a problem. I'm studying Javascript with Node and Express all by myself and I'm not sure about what I'm asking, but I'll try to explain myself somehow.

I'm using Express and I have quite a long response from the node server to a GET request. It is handled by an express router. The response is basically a `SELECT` query to my database, which has got quite a long callback with a forEach loop. This loop contains some prepared statements that fire on every loop cycle. Each one of these queries has another callback that handles some values, resolves promises, etc.

Just to visualize the structure:

```
router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {

  parser.on('end', function(p) {  // some event function
    db.query("SELECT * FROM aziende", function (err, result, fields) {  // first sql query (I'm using mysql2 npm packet)
      bigArray.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (condition) {
          db.execute(query, [item.prop1, item.prop2, item.prop3], function(err2, result2) { ... }); // first prepared statement with callback
        } else {
          db.execute(query2, [item.prop1, item.prop2, item.prop3], function(err3, result3) { ... }); // second prepared statement + callback
        }
      });
    });
  });

});
```

As you see, it's a very nested structure.

The user launches this process from a button on the browser. What I want to do is guarantee a way to stop the process in every moment just by pushing another 'Stop' button. But I don't know how and if it's possible to clean the callback queue of the server. I'm talking about hundreds of queries. The `forEach` loop seems to get to its end quite fast, but the callback queue can take some seconds up to minutes (20-30 minutes) to get completed. As you'll understand, I cannot block the user for all this time.

Hope you can help.

P.S: I'm already using socket.io to notify the user about the status of the server elaboration (by using progress bars on the browser), so if an hypothetical solution to my problem expects a socket technology to be accomplished, then is well accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async/await style instead of callbacks.
You can return a Promise that you reject if you click on a `Stop` button.

Comment: And when I reject the promise, how do I actually stop the query? In other words, what should I write in the ```.catch()``` block of the promise?

Comment: Maybe something like this even if i'm not sure it stops queries.

`function executeQueries() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    stopButton.addEventListener("click", reject, { once: true });
    await Promise.all(
      bigArray.map((item, index) => condition
        ? db.execute(query, [item.prop1, item.prop2, item.prop3], function(err2, result2) { ... }); // first prepared statement with callback
        :  db.execute(query2, [item.prop1, item.prop2, item.prop3], function(err3, result3) { ... }); // second prepared statement + callback
    resolve();
  });
}`